# cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() return no integer

Tags: visual-studio-2010

In my visual studio 2010,  vb.net

```
Dim rowsAffect As Integer

sql = "Update temptable Set Exp_Amt=0 Where Exp_Amt is Null"
cmd.CommandText = sql
rowsAffect = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

When I debug this by use F10 key , rowsAffect = &HD .

Actually , rowsAffect value should be number 1 or 2 or something like that.

Is it need to change setting in VS 2010 IDE ?

Comment: `&HD` = 13 decimal. It's just showing you the value in hexadecimal form.

Comment: yes hexadecimal form, but i want to get integer form , how can I do it?

Comment: Damien_The_Unbeliever . you right  ,thank for your correction :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change how numbers are shown in the Watch, Locals, or Autos Window<sup>1</sup>, whilst debugging, you should right-click within the grid and tick (for hex) or untick (for decimal) the `Hexadecimal Display` option.

<sup>1</sup>Possibly others also, you haven't said where you're seeing this value, but those are the most obvious ones.